# Class object mistaken as an int

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am making a tree class to practice, and I have arrived at this.

```
class Node():
def __init__(self,val):
    self.val = val
    self.right = None
    self.left = None
    self.count = 1
def add(self,node):
    if self.val > node.val:
        if self.left == None:
            self.left = node
        else:
            self.left.add(node)
    elif self.val < node.val:
        if self.right == None:
            self.right = node
        else:
            self.right.add(node)
    else:
        self.count +=1
def count(self):
    if self.right and self.left:
        self.right.count()
        self.left.count()
    elif self.right:
        print(self.value)
        self.right.count()
    elif self.left:
        print(self.value)
        self.left.count()
    else:
        pass
```

But, when calling it, I have a problem.

```
a = Node('a')
>>> a.add(Node('a'))
>>> a.add(Node('b'))
>>> a.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#73>", line 1, in <module>
    a.count()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> 

>>> type(a.right)
<class '__main__.Node'>
```

How can I fix this? Through debugging, it seems the problem is at self.right.count() function. Also, I am on Python 3.9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer referred to in the error is `a.count`.  The problem is that `count` is used in two ways by the class:  (1) as a method name, and (2) as an instance attribute name.

When an instance of `Node` is created, the `__init__` method creates an instance attribute `count` in the following:

```
    self.count = 1
```

This masks the method of the same name.  So when you do `a.count()`, it's using `1` for `a.count`.

To fix it, just use different names for method vs. the instance attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You have an int field and method `count`. Rename one of them and problem will be solved. Also you have

```
print(self.value)
```

line, but your field name is val.